# 0x0 empty GraphicsPlaceholder

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to extract data (X and Y-axis values) from line graph matlab. I have tried with this code:

```
fig = openfig('graphA.fig')
ax = fig.Children
ln = ax.Children;
X = ln.XData;
Y = ln.YData;
```

but it turned out to give me this error:

> Unrecognized method, property, or field 'XData' for class
> 'matlab.graphics.GraphicsPlaceholder'.
>
> Error in graph_data (line 7) X = ln.XData;

This is output from workspace:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: When you run the line `ax = fig.Children` it seems there are 2 children handle returned in the `ax` handle. You should try inspecting the children of each object contained in `ax` then one of these object is going to be the line you're after.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract data from saved figure of MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31482916/how-to-extract-data-from-saved-figure-of-matlab)

Answer (score 0):

It should work like this:

```
h = findobj(gca,'Type','line')
x=get(h,'Xdata') ;
y=get(h,'Ydata') ;
```

[Source](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/383567-how-to-extract-x-y-data-values-from-matlab-figure)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried, but the output at the workspace is like this:
h=0x0 GraphicsPlaceholder 
x= []
y= []
so I still can’t get any value for x and y axis
Please help

Comment: For this to work, the figure has to be open. For more details please check the source provided, which also features an alternative solution

Comment: I have tried all solutions you mentioned but still didn't work. I still got empty array for all lines.

Answer (score 0):

I had a somewhat similar issue when I was trying to extract data from a large scatter plot. In the property inspector, I saw the Axes>Scatter property but could not access it by *findobj* command. It turned out, that the *HandleVisibility* for the scatter data was turned OFF which caused the issue. Setting it manually to ON, I could access the XData and YData.